# c iterate over an array

Tags: c, arrays

i have some issue with my code 
i read a file and i push the data inside the file into a struct data type

but when iterate over the dataValue which should be an array of struct
it give me the same dataValue and specificly the last one in the file.

```
int main() {
    FILE *file;
    struct characteristic {
        double * dval;
        double n;
        char * name;
    };
    struct characteristic dataValue[150];
    if ((file = fopen("/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/data", "r"))
            == NULL) {
        puts("error reading file");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        double var1, var2, var3, var4;
        char * etiq = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        while (fscanf(file, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%s \n", &var1, &var2, &var3, &var4,
                etiq) != EOF) {
            struct characteristic *new_node;
            new_node = (struct characteristic *) malloc(
                    sizeof(struct characteristic));
            new_node->dval = &var1;
            (new_node->dval)++;
            new_node->dval = &var2;
            (new_node->dval)++;
            new_node->dval = &var3;
            (new_node->dval)++;
            new_node->dval = &var4;
            new_node->name = etiq;
            puts("=================================================");

            printf("the name of characteristic number %d est : %s .\n", i,
                    new_node->name);
            dataValue[i].dval = new_node->dval;
            dataValue[i].name = new_node->name;
            dataValue[i].n = i;
            i++;
        }

    }
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(dataValue) / sizeof(struct characteristic); i++) {
        printf("second name of characteristic number %d est : %s .\n", i,
                dataValue[i].name);
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            printf("bla value of vector number %d at index %d est : %lf \n", i,
                    j, *(dataValue[i].dval + j));
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the file containe data like :
1.0,2.7,4.9,1.5,name

Comment: `(new_node->dval)++` is incrementing the pointer, Afterwards you are assigning it with an address  `&var4` in the end. What is the point of all of this exercise?

Comment: i'm a java programmer c it's a bit hard for me 'i studiy it by doing some exercice like this', i should read a file and push the data to an array of struct and at the end apply some algorithm to this data

Answer (score 3):

Your code is using an uninitialized pointer `dval`, and you are assigning it addresses of local variables that go out of scope before you print. This is not the way to create arrays in C.

You can allocate the array into `dval` by using `malloc`, but then you would have to `free()` that array as well. Since you know that there's going to be four `double`s in the node, it would be simpler to make `dval` an array of four items, like this:

```
struct characteristic {
    double dval[4];
    double n;
    char * name;
};
```

Now you can do the assignments using either the pointer or the array syntax:

```
dataValue[i].dval[0] = var1;
dataValue[i].dval[1] = var2;
dataValue[i].dval[2] = var3;
dataValue[i].dval[3] = var4;
dataValue[i].n = i;
// Store etiq in the name, or make a copy:
dataValue[i].name = etiq;
// Prepare etiq for the next loop
etiq = malloc(100); // No need to multiply by sizeof(char)
```

Comment: thanis you for your help, i have an additionnal question why i cant use this :dataValue = new_node; or dataValue[i] = new_node; before the enf of while loop

Comment: @lsroudi You don't need `new_node` and dynamic allocation for it at all. `malloc` gives you a pointer, but `dataValue` already has full `struct`, ready to accept your data directly. All you need to do is to allocate new `etiq` in for the `name` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You `struct` contains a pointer to double `double *dval`. It seems you intend to use it as an array of 4 doubles. But you are not allocating memory for 4 doubles. The recommended way to store 4 doubles in your `struct` would be to define an array inside it.

```
struct characteristic {
    double dval[4];
    double n;
    char * name;
};
```

There is a similar issue with the `name`. You allocate memory of 100 bytes once outside the while loop and obtain a pointer called `etiq`. Then for each element of `dataValue` you set `name` to the same pointer `etiq` to the same block that you are simply overwriting with `fscanf`. If you want a `char*` and not a char array in your `struct` use `strdup` to copy the string to a newly allocated memory block (and remember to free it independently from the struct). E.g.

```
new_node->name = strdup(etiq);
```

Or define `name` in your struct as `char name[100]` and either use `strcpy` or pass `name` directly to `fscanf`